# Chemistry.SE ad barely readable due to bad color contrast

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, advertising

Today, I noticed this Chemistry.SE ad on Programmers.SE:

[image]

I find that this combination of dark blue text on a dark green background very hard to read (and the white shadow doesn't really improve the situation).

Could the color contrast be improved?

Comment: Perhaps you could post this on Chemistry Meta instead.

Comment: @HDE226868 From a practical viewpoint, it would likely be doomed to oblivion there, seeing that the only persons who could do anything about it will probably already have a hard time noticing this bug here on the main meta. But sure, from a proper policy viewpoint it might indeed be more appropriate there.

Comment: Better the movies and TV http://i.stack.imgur.com/gC2cN.png

Comment: Related bug-report on a per-site meta: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1916/49.

Comment: @Paweł Why did your edit have to go through [peer review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/44165), when you're a SE employee? Is it because meta.SE is not considered a meta site? Is it a bug?

Comment: @Paweł you really better ask for a diamond so you can mark stuff as completed (or declined :)) all on your own. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yea, i may need to ask for diamond:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems resolved now.

[image]

[image]

Can be checked on live by [this shortcut link](https://stackexchange.com/ads/launched-question) after few/lots of refresh.

**Update:-** After the redesigning of HNQ ad, the base image has been altered a bit but mostly change is in size:

[image]

<sub>Note: Currently can't find any active HNQ image ad question to check the changes in text font and shadow , if any.</sub>

Comment: After few/lots of/lots of lots of.