# Movies & TV hot network question ads have poor colouring. Please improve it?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hot-questions, sidebar

A hot network question just showed up on [RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) for Movies & TV, which is fine, but its colouring is nuts:

> [image: Why is Penny less concerned about the "check engine" light?]

Could M&TV have their ad adjusted slightly so that it doesn't do uncomfortable things to my eyes?

Comment: This is ... not Sparta... ugly.

Comment: This has also been adressed in two separate questions on [meta.movies.se], one about the [background image](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1917/49) and one about the [font color](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1916/49), which is in turn related to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/265870/162011) about the [chemistry.se] ad.

Comment: I made a new update to my answer after they fixed the font/shadow. Seems solved now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UDPATE 2015-09-15:** The font color seems to have been fixed to some degree into plain white, which makes it less agressively fighting with the background (that [has been fixed](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1926/49), too) and improves readability.

[image]

However, I'd still not consider this solved yet, since the current plain white text and the very bold and blurry font is still quite hard on the eyes.

---

**UDPATE 2015-09-22:** So, the problems with the thick font/white drop shadow seem to have been solved now, too. With those changes I'd consider all the problems with our HNQ ad solved now:

[image]

Comment: It still seems to have its white drop-shadow. Removing that would improve things.

Comment: The deslgn makes "dld" look weird.